# How do you initialize a global variable only when its not defined?

Tags: python, dictionary, global

I have a global dictionary variable that will be used in a function that gets called multiple times. I don't have control of when the function is called, or a scope outside of the function I'm writing.  I need to initialize the variable only if its not initialized.  Once initialized, I will add values to it.

```
global dict
if dict is None:
    dict = {}

dict[lldb.thread.GetThreadID()] = dict[lldb.thread.GetThreadID()] + 1
```

Unfortunately, I get

```
NameError: global name 'dict' is not defined
```

I understand that I should define the variable, but since this code is called multiple times, by just saying `dict = {}` I would be RE-defining the variable every time the code is called, unless I can somehow check if it's not defined, and only define it then.

Comment: You can catch the `NameError` and then set it there ... With that said, this seems like a odd design decision.  Can you provide more context?

Comment: Also, it's not clear what's going on here ... Your error says "`test2`", your code says `dict` and has a `global` statement outside of a function ... It'd be really helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: yes, the code gets executed by a debugger when a breakpoint is hit.  so the debugger is the one calling the code.  Also, I am a python beginner :(

Comment: sorry I had renamed the variable for posting on stackoverflow, test2 was a mistake it should just be dict.. i corrected it

Comment: With this little context it's hard to figure out why you need a global and wether or not this is the best approach. I tend to define global variables (like constants, or some status related variables, for instance `my_dictionary = {}`) at the begining of the module and then state `global my_dictionary` inside each funtion wherever it's needed. And, as a thumb rule, I wouldn't use reserved keywords or builtin type names as variables names.

Comment: @VictorDomingos absolutely sounds correct regarding global use.  This code gets called by a debugger, and I'm trying to maintain some context between those calls.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Catching the error:

```
try:
    _ = myDict
except NameError:
    global myDict
    myDict = {}
```

### IMPORTANT NOTE:

Do **NOT** use `dict` or any other built-in type as a variable name.

Comment: To the OP: The note at the bottom of this is very important

Comment: @PaulH -- Especially since you have to do some really aweful things in order to have the name `dict` raise a `NameError` ...

Comment: THANK YOU :) i think it worked..  it gives a warning SyntaxWarning: name 'myDict' is used prior to global declaration but thats fine by me

Answer (score 3):

A more idiomatic way to do this is to set the name ahead of time to a sentinel value and then check against that:

```
_my_dict = None

...

def increment_thing():
    global _my_dict
    if _my_dict is None:
        _my_dict = {}
    thread_id = lldb.thread.GetThreadID()
    _my_dict[thread_id] = _my_dict.get(thread_id, 0) + 1
```

---

Note, I don't know anything about `lldb` -- but if it is using *python* threads, you might be better off using a `threading.local`:

```
import threading

# Thread local storage
_tls = threading.local()

def increment_thing():
    counter = getattr(_tls, 'counter', 0)
    _tls.counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: thank you @mgilson :) I will try your solution as well.  I will have to figure out how to do the first definition of _my_dict and do it BEFORE debugger calls the incrementing code